# MySql - Query with group by and case

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do a query using `case when` and `group by` but I can't get the correct result.

So, I have this query:

```
select date, type, DAYNAME(date) as dia, count( date) as total ,
 CASE WHEN type = 1 THEN COUNT(date) ELSE 0 END as admin,
 CASE WHEN type = 2 THEN COUNT(date) ELSE 0 END as dis 
from `user_access` 
where `date` >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY 
group by DAYNAME(date), type
limit 7;
```

And I have this result:
[image]

It duplicates the records by `dayname column` and don't put `admin` and `dis` records in same line.

But what I need is this:

```
date       | type | dia     | total | admin | dis |
-----------|------|---------|-------|-------|-----|
2018-10-08 |1     |Monday   | 3     | 3     | 0   |
2018-10-09 |1     |Tuesday  | 6     | 1     | 5   |
2018-10-10 |1     |Wednesday| 3     | 2     | 1   |
```

I already try put other columns in group by but doesn't work.

If I remove `type` from group by and select, returns me this with this query:

```
    select date, DAYNAME(date) as dia, count( date) as total ,
    CASE WHEN type = 1 THEN COUNT(date) ELSE 0 END as admin,
    CASE WHEN type = 2 THEN COUNT(date) ELSE 0 END as dis 
from `user_access` 
where `date` >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY 
group by DAYNAME(date)
limit 7;

date       | dia     | total | admin | dis |
-----------|---------|-------|-------|-----|
2018-10-08 |Monday   | 3     | 3     | 0   |
2018-10-09 |Tuesday  | 6     | 6     | 0   |
2018-10-10 |Wednesday| 5     | 3     | 0   |
```

Puts all records in case to admin column...

This makes me sense, but I'm doing something wrong, maybe the `case`.

How can I solve this?

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand how and why `type=2` becomes `type=1` . Anyway, it seems like all you have to do is exclude `type` this from the select list and group by columns .

Comment: type = 2 and type = 1 tells me the if the user is administrator or operator. If I take off type from group by it returns me 3 rows but put all values in admin column and dis column is 0 in all rows @sagi

Comment: I didn't mean to take the `CASE EXPRESSION` down , I mean to take it from the select columns and group by columns .

Comment: `SELECT date,DAYNAME(date)..(SAME)..GROUP BY DAYNAME(date)`

Comment: @sagi, I update the question if remove the type from select and group by

Comment: COUNT(0) is same as COUNT(id). Both will count as one row. In your else statement, instead of 0, return `null`

Comment: Can you please paste your origin sample's data here?

Comment: @sagi, I update the question with query without type

Comment: @sagi your suggestief query approach is wrong it’s not valid ansi sql.. because is misusing mysql extended group by feature

Comment: @RaymondNijland You're right, wasn't paying attention , although it will work . Fixed .

Comment: @sagi not when the server is running only full group by als active sql mode.. Beside the mysql group by can cause unrelated data for the selected column which are not in de group by

Comment: I'm not arguing.. This type of coding shouldn't be used . @RaymondNijland

Comment: @user3242861 
Also using LIMIT without ORDER BY is meaningless because SQL is a unsorted dataset so MySQL is free to return anny records in the table/record set as the first seven rows.. Besides MySQL 8.0 does not autosort GROUP BY clauses annymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the query you want :

```
select MAX(date), DAYNAME(date) as dia, count( date) as total ,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN type = 1 THEN 1 END) as admin,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN type = 2 THEN 1 END) as dis 
from `user_access` 
where `date` >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY 
group by DAYNAME(date);
```

Comment: Also using LIMIT without ORDER BY is meaningless because SQL is a unsorted dataset so MySQL is free to return anny records in the table/record set as the first seven rows.. Besides MySQL 8.0 does not autosort GROUP BY clauses annymore.

Comment: Actually specifically here the limit doesn’t do anything , the query is grouped by day name , and there are only 7 so its really meaningless..